# execute procedure in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, procedure

I have typed a procedure using the web interface of the Oracle 10g. Compile the code and no error at all. For executing this procedure I should use the command EXECUTE name, but when I put that into a SQL window it does not work at all and says that is an invalid SQL command. The question that I have is how I can execute that procedure? I can access it by the Object Browser, but nothing more.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to execute your procedure enclose it with `begin` `end` block. `Execute` command is sql*plus's command. To that end to execute your procedure you might write:

```
begin 
  your_procedure_name;
end;
```

and in sql*plus you would use `exec` or `execute`(which implicitly encloses your procedure  with `begin` `end` block):

```
SQL> exec your_procedure_name;
```

Comment: thanks, but when I want to run it, this error appears: object SYSTEM.myprocedure is invalid, why is that so?

Comment: @Manolo It's because your procedure has a syntax error(or more than one). Check your procedure for correctness. And try to avoid storing user objects in the `system`  schema.